# RubyMotion error

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymotion

I just started learning ruby motion and at the beginning of a tutorial I have hit a road block! The tutorial is "RubyMotion iOS Development Essentials".

Here is my code:

```
class RootController < UIViewController
    def viewDidLoad
    alert = UIAlertView.alloc.initWithTitle "This is foo title",
    message:"Do you like this example?",
    delegate: nil,
    cancelButtonTitles: "cancel",
    otherButtonTitles: "Yes", "No", nil
    alert.show
    end
end
```

I know the indentation looks funny, but apparently that is RubyMotion syntax... Weird, I know.
And here is the error I am receiving, regarding the "initWithTitle" method:

```
(main)> 2013-12-13 00:44:40.780 HelloWorld[97435:80b] root_controller.rb:7:in `viewDidLoad': undefined method `initWithTitle' for #<UIAlertView:0x8d2bcf0> (NoMethodError)
    from app_delegate.rb:6:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'
2013-12-13 00:44:40.782 HelloWorld[97435:80b] root_controller.rb:7:in `viewDidLoad': undefined method `initWithTitle' for #<UIAlertView:0x8d2bcf0> (NoMethodError)
    from app_delegate.rb:6:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'
2013-12-13 00:44:40.784 HelloWorld[97435:80b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NoMethodError', reason: 'root_controller.rb:7:in `viewDidLoad': undefined method `initWithTitle' for #<UIAlertView:0x8d2bcf0> (NoMethodError)
    from app_delegate.rb:6:in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'
```

'

I would appreciate any pointers, it's a major bummer to get stuck this early on!

Comment: RubyMotion is a toolchain that lets you develop using RUBY, so the way you indent the code (the Ruby code) it's not the proper way (the usual and  more readable way). Seeing the trace, It seems you're missing the definition of the method `initWithTitle`. Try `p UIAlertView.alloc.methods` to see if it's already defined with another name.

Comment: @kira, The method is already defined      initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cancelButtonTitles` should be singular: `cancelButtonTitle`.

Because you're using plural wording, it can't find a matching method signature.